# Display an object in Vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an object like:

```js
Obj = {
  'min_mix': 1, 
  'max_mix': 2,
  'climbing': {
    'easy':[
      {
        'hour': 1.0, 
        'id':0,
      }
    ],
    'height': [
      {
        'hour': 1.0, 
        'price': 100
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have to display this in my HTML:

```
min_mix : 1
max_mix : 2

climbing:

easy: 
hour : 1.0
id : 0

height:
hour: 1.0
price: 100
```

For now I use some v-for, but I don't have a good result,
I don't understand how display correctly the array in easy and height?

https://jsfiddle.net/CanadianDevGuy/fjaoztgn/15/

Comment: What do you mean by `don't have a good result`? What does it display currently, and what is the desired result? Can you share the code you have currently?

Comment: I made a JSfiddle to show, I need to display text easy and height in text , not in array

Comment: I get a 404 Not Found when trying to open the jsfiddle link.

Comment: I edit it in my post

Comment: I also don't need the 0 after min_mix and max_mix, just the value 1

Answer (score 1):

Please check this  https://jsfiddle.net/Lewvsp0k/

```
<v-card-text v-for='(value,name) in obj' :key='name' class="pt-0 pb-0">
      <template v-if="typeof value !== 'object'">
                    <b>{{name}} : {{ value }} </b> 
              </template>
              <template v-else>
                <div v-for="(rowValue, rowIndex) in value" :key='rowIndex' class="mb-2 pa-0">
                 <b>{{name}} :  </b> 

                  <div v-for="(rowValue1, rowIndex1) in rowValue" :key='rowIndex1' class="mb-2 pa-0">
                     <b>{{rowIndex1}}  : </b> 
                 <div>

                   <div v-for="rowValue2 in rowValue1" :key='rowValue2' class="mb-2 pa-0">

                  <div v-for="(rowValue3, rowIndex3) in rowValue2" :key='rowValue3' class="mb-2 pa-0">
                     <b> {{rowIndex3}} : {{rowValue3}}  </b> 

                   </div>
                </div>
               </div>
            </div>

         </div>
       </template>
</v-card-text>
```

Comment: @TheDevGuy Please check this

Answer (score 0):

Should work

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in Obj ">
<template v-if="typeof item !== Object">
    <div :key="index">
        {{ index }} : {{ item }}
    </div>
</template>
<template v-else>
    <div :key="'subitem' + indexSubItem" v-for="(subItem, indexSubItem) in item">
        {{ indexSubItem }} : {{ subItem }}
    </div>
</template>
</template>
```

Comment: I try it but nothing in fiddle

Comment: An array is an object and your `typeof` comparaison should have a string on the right side `typeof item !== 'object'`. I think it's better you use `array instanceof Array` to check if it's an array, and the else will be the object/value comparaison. This is not recursive however, so `climbing` which is an object, will not show it's arrays properly. Also, how about you leave a bit of explanation as to *why* and *how* you think it should work? Code only answers should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to actually create a new component, say `<object-entry>`, that can perform iterative nesting logic: if the value it encounters is a string or number, we print it out directly; otherwise, we nest another level of `<object-entry>` in it.

The `<object-entry>` component (you can also rename it to anything you like, that makes more sense) will do the following:

1. always print the key from the key-value pair.
2. decide if it should print the value from the key-value pair:

   - if value is a typeof string/number, we print it
   - if value is not (then it is an array or object), we then call the component itself again (effectively nesting itself recursively)

In pseudo-code it looks like this:

```
<div>
    <strong>{{ key }}</strong>: 

    <template v-if="isStringOrNumber(value)">
        {{ value }}
    </template>

    <object-entry
        v-else />

</div>
```

This ensures that we will keep indenting until we encounter the "bottommost" value that is either a number or string.

---

**Note:** You cannot truly get rid of the object index in the markup, due to the way your data is structured: if `climbing` is supposed to only contain 'easy' and 'height', they should not be double nested inside a meaningless key of `0`. Likewise, for `easy` and `height`, it makes little sense they are stored as array of objects when it should be just an object itself.

---

See proof-of-concept here, with suggested changes to your data (you can also use your original data structure, but it will come with an extraneous level of nesting):

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

Vue.component('object-entry', {
  template: '#object-entry-template',
  props: ['entryKey', 'entryValue'],
  methods: {
    isStringOrNumber: function(v) {
      return typeof v === 'string' || typeof v === 'number';
    }
  }
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    obj: {
      'min_mix': 1,
      'max_mix': 1,
      'climbing': {
        'easy': {
          'hour': 1.0,
          'id': 0
        },
        'height': {
          'hour': 1.0,
          'price': 100.0
        }
      }
    },
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <object-entry
      v-for="(value, key) in obj" 
      v-bind:key="key"
      v-bind:entry-key="key"
      v-bind:entry-value="value" />
  </v-app>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="object-entry-template">
  <v-card-text class="pt-0 pb-0">
    <strong>{{ entryKey }}</strong> :
    
    <template v-if="isStringOrNumber(entryValue)">
      {{ entryValue }}
    </template>

    <!-- Here, the component nests itself if value is not a string/number -->
    <object-entry
      v-else
      v-for="(value, key) in entryValue"
      v-bind:key="key"
      v-bind:entry-key="key"
      v-bind:entry-value="value" />
  </v-card-text>
</script>
```

Comment: I works in fiddle but how can I use in my code editor , I don,t understand the object entry

Comment: @TheDevGuy Just copy and paste it in your code? The code above is based off the code you've shared in your Fiddle. Of course, ideally, the inline component template should be moved into its own file. I do not know how your app is designed and how it is built, so I can't give you a definite answer.

Comment: have you doc for object-entry ?

Comment: @TheDevGuy It's a custom component that I've written in the code above: it is not a documented component that VueJS has. You can rename it `<my-favourite-unicorn>` for all I care :) If you re-read my answer: *The easiest way is to actually create a new component, say `<object-entry>`*